# Add space between automatically broken lines

Tags: php, html

I have a line of text which when broken due to a lack of space, has its letters overlap with the first line.

For example, in the following line, the bottom line would be shifter up until the dots of the "i"s are touching the bottom parts of the letter in the first line.

info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info info

I have to echo the html inside the php for a particular reason. How can I add space between the two lines?

```
echo '<div align="center">';
echo '<div style="width:80%;line-height:10px">';
echo '<div align="left">';
echo '<p style="margin-top:20px;line-height:10px;margin-bottom:10px">'.$array[$i].'</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo "<br>";
echo "<hr>";
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: The cause is probably `line-height:10px`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are constraining your text to only 10px.  You may want to change the font size to be smaller or your line height to be bigger.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_box_model